# google chrome td Html tables issue

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, overflow

maybe my question has been repeated but please read my question carefully and give me suggestion, thanks in advance.

I am web developer, in one page I have a Table which is created by dataTable of jQuery. this table is populated perfectly. but unfortunately 2 problems occur:

1- if I put table-layout:auto this table will be expanded out of div container , if I omit, and put table-layout:fixed  the columns of table are overlapped .Let me tell you that my table has two expandable block columns that in default situation are close but after click on them are expanded.
2- I have no problem with overflow:auto but this feature does not work.

**limitation**: I am looking for a table with single line for each row.break word is not acceptable for me.

all of these problems exist in ie9 and google chrome and I donot have problem with firefox.

any suggeestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your HTML to the question.

Comment: @snazi or an example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)